# Make Screen 'Edges' (Cocos2D)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am new to Cocos2D and I want to know how to make a screen edge/border for my game so that the character won't fall out of the screen. I read somewhere that you can do this either by Cocos2D or Box2D and I don't care which I use but I am just not sure where to begin. I only need a edge on the top and bottom of the device. It also would be nice if these values were not hard coded since this will be a universal app.

Also when I actually make the border, what is the real way to ***stop*** the character from going out of the screen? Should I just set gravity off or to 0?

Does anyone know how I can go upon doing this?

I am really struggling figuring this out!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're game is using quartz, then each UI object you have should have a bounding box. This can be access similar to the following code.

```
UIImage *hero = [[UIImage alloc]initWithImage:image];

CGRect heroBoundingBox = hero.frame;
```

The UIViewController that the game is within will also have a bounding box as well. The simplest way to check to see if the hero is on the screen is to use CGRectContainsRect.

```
UIImage *hero = [[UIImage alloc]initWithImage:image];

CGRect heroBoundingBox = hero.frame;

CGRect screenBoundingBox = viewController.frame;

bool heroOnScreen = CGRectContainsRect(screenBoundingBox, heroBoundingBox);
```

Then just setup some code like this:

```
if (heroOnScreen) {
    //continue moving hero
} else {
    //move hero back on screen
}
```

Its hard to say what you need to do for this without seeing any example code or knowing more about how this works. Hopefully this will help though.

Comment: How would I apply this to Cocos2d though? I know Cocos2d works with bounding box but I am not coding my game part in Obj-C :/

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of how you're implementing the character and moving him? I'm only use to working in objective-c but if I see how you're doing it I might be able to adapt it.

Comment: Found the documentation for Cocos2D. Looks like a lot of objects still have a CGRect that defines them or a CGPoint (in which case you can use CGRectContainsPoint instead). What object are you using for your character? If its the CCSprite then you would get the textureRect property instead of the frame property to get the CGRect you need for the CGRectContainsRect method.

Comment: Ahh I gotcha, I will try to implement it your way, although I'm not sure if it is the best way though